# Is there an efficient way to calculate last digits of this sum?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a more efficient way to find the last digits of the following sum for any $n$?

$1 + n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... + \frac{n}{2!} + n!$

The method I currently use to find the last $d$ digits of the sum is as follows:

Let $M$ be $n \bmod 10^d$, or $n \bmod 10^d +10^d$ if $n \bmod 10^d < 5\times d$, since an additional step would affect the result if the latter is true. Evaluate $1 + M + M (M-1)$, then add $M(M-1)(M-2)$, and continue until the number of desired digits stabilize.

This can be done quickly for a small number of digits, but for, say, 20 digits, it would be very time-consuming. Is there a way to program this in Mathematica? As far as I'm sure, this would require a loop that references the number of iterations that have been looped, which the `Nest` function doesn't do.

Answer (score 10):

There is some *undocumented* functionality in *Mathematica* that allows you to work with a factored representation of integers, encapsulated as the object `` Internal`FactoredNumber[] ``. This has associated operators such as `` Internal`FactoredNumberTimes[] `` and `` Internal`FactoredNumberPlus[] `` that can be used on it, as well as the conversion functions `` Internal`ToFactoredNumber[] ``, `` Internal`FromFactoredNumber[] ``, and, most importantly for our purposes, `` Internal`FromFactoredNumberMod[] ``.

Applied to this problem, we can use these operations along with `Fold[]`/`FoldList[]`:

```
With[{n = 20, m = 1*^5}, 
    Internal`FromFactoredNumberMod[Fold[Internal`FactoredNumberPlus, 1, 
                                        FoldList[Internal`FactoredNumberTimes, 
                                                 Internal`ToFactoredNumber /@
                                                 Range[n, 2, -1]]], m]]
   40001
```

Compare this with

```
With[{n = 20, m = 1*^5}, 
     Mod[Sum[FactorialPower[n, k], {k, 0, n - 1}], m]]
   40001
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but there's a direct way of calculating this sum, expressed in terms of an incomplete gamma function:

```
f[n_] = Sum[n!/k!, {k, 0, n}] // FullSimplify
(*    E * Gamma[n+1, 1]    *)
```

Computing the last four digits, for example, directly (without explicit summing):

```
Mod[f[1234], 10^4]
(*    7685    *)
```